# Проблема с cdn от yandex

Tags: javascript, cdn

Есть сайт. На нём до меня подключали скрипты от cdn yandex'a. Когда в Украине запретили этот ресурс - все перестало работать. Однако, когда захожу на этот сайт через vpn, всё хорошо.

- Скрипты подключены типа jquery,bootstrap.
- Менял на другие cdn, не помогает.

Подскажите, в чем дело?)

Comment: Ну так если яндекс недоступен, как с него ресурсы-то загрузятся?

Comment: Есть вариант прописать другие домены яндекса (где-то пробегала инфа, что не все домены яндекса со статикой попали под фильтр), но надёжнее выбрать другой CDN, не под санкциями. Ну, либо ждать (возможно, долго) пока политика не устаканится.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что топикстартер дал ответ на свой вопрос строчкой ранее.

Comment: В чём дело: в том, что в Украине запретили этот ресурс.

Comment: Спасибо ) уже менял на другие cdn